# Using SafeAreaView with BottomNavigation in Expo Go and Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

In React Native with Expo Go, I am trying to use the  with  in Expo Go. However when wrapping the Bottom Navigation into the SaveAreaView, the bottom navigation doesn't show.

Code below with SafeAreaView:

```
// components/HomeScren.js

// Import for React
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

// Import for React Native Paper
import { Text, BottomNavigation } from 'react-native-paper';

const MusicRoute = () => <Text>Music</Text>;

const AlbumsRoute = () => <Text>Albums</Text>;

const RecentsRoute = () => <Text>Recents</Text>;

const NotificationsRoute = () => <Text>Notifications</Text>;

export const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    const [routes] = useState([
        { key: 'music', title: 'Favorites', focusedIcon: 'heart', unfocusedIcon: 'heart-outline'},
        { key: 'albums', title: 'Albums', focusedIcon: 'album' },
        { key: 'recents', title: 'Recents', focusedIcon: 'history' },
        { key: 'notifications', title: 'Notifications', focusedIcon: 'bell', unfocusedIcon: 'bell-outline' },
      ]);
    
    const renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
        music: MusicRoute,
        albums: AlbumsRoute,
        recents: RecentsRoute,
        notifications: NotificationsRoute,
    });
    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <BottomNavigation
                navigationState={{ index, routes }}
                onIndexChange={setIndex}
                renderScene={renderScene}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

Result screen on Android via Expo Go App
[image]

When I remove the SaveAreaView, the bottom navigation showed. Code below and screenshot

```
// components/HomeScren.js

// Import for React
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

// Import for React Native Paper
import { Text, BottomNavigation } from 'react-native-paper';

const MusicRoute = () => <Text>Music</Text>;

const AlbumsRoute = () => <Text>Albums</Text>;

const RecentsRoute = () => <Text>Recents</Text>;

const NotificationsRoute = () => <Text>Notifications</Text>;

export const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    const [routes] = useState([
        { key: 'music', title: 'Favorites', focusedIcon: 'heart', unfocusedIcon: 'heart-outline'},
        { key: 'albums', title: 'Albums', focusedIcon: 'album' },
        { key: 'recents', title: 'Recents', focusedIcon: 'history' },
        { key: 'notifications', title: 'Notifications', focusedIcon: 'bell', unfocusedIcon: 'bell-outline' },
      ]);
    
    const renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
        music: MusicRoute,
        albums: AlbumsRoute,
        recents: RecentsRoute,
        notifications: NotificationsRoute,
    });
    return (
            <BottomNavigation
                navigationState={{ index, routes }}
                onIndexChange={setIndex}
                renderScene={renderScene}
            />
    )
}
```

Screenshot for the code above:

[image]

Content of package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "expo": "~48.0.10",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.6",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Is there any way to use Bottom Navigation inside Save Area View?

Comment: You may try adding style `flex: 1` into `<SafeAreaView>`. See React Native docs [https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview#example](https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview#example).

Comment: Your suggestion works... If you add an answer below, I will mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, based on the Safe Area View from React Native Documentation https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview#example, the Safe Area View should be styled with flex: 1.

I missed this because I am using Safe Area View from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-safe-area-context, not from default react native package.

Complete working code below. Notice the additional StyleSheet at the bottom.

```
// components/HomeScren.js

// Import for React
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

// Import for React Native Paper
import { Text, BottomNavigation } from 'react-native-paper';

const MusicRoute = () => <Text>Music</Text>;

const AlbumsRoute = () => <Text>Albums</Text>;

const RecentsRoute = () => <Text>Recents</Text>;

const NotificationsRoute = () => <Text>Notifications</Text>;

export const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    const [routes] = useState([
        { key: 'music', title: 'Favorites', focusedIcon: 'heart', unfocusedIcon: 'heart-outline'},
        { key: 'albums', title: 'Albums', focusedIcon: 'album' },
        { key: 'recents', title: 'Recents', focusedIcon: 'history' },
        { key: 'notifications', title: 'Notifications', focusedIcon: 'bell', unfocusedIcon: 'bell-outline' },
      ]);
    
    const renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
        music: MusicRoute,
        albums: AlbumsRoute,
        recents: RecentsRoute,
        notifications: NotificationsRoute,
    });
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={ styles.safeArea }>
            <BottomNavigation
                navigationState={{ index, routes }}
                onIndexChange={setIndex}
                renderScene={renderScene}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    safeArea: {
      flex: 1,
    },
  });
```

Resulting screen in Expo Go

[image]